# android disable lint "unused declaration" for entire project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, lint

In an android library project I have many unused declarations, cause they mostly get called from outside of the project. I use lint via

> Analyze -> Inspect Code

I dont want to use

```
@SurpressWarning("unused")
```

on each file.

If I try to disable it with the same ID in gradle file

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        disable 'unused'
    }
}
```

The linter still comes up with the "Unused declaration" errors

I also tried it by creating `lint.xml` file in project root

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <!-- list of issues to configure -->
    <issue id="unused" severity="ignore" /> 
</lint>
```

But it still doesn´t work. Anyone know the correct lint ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Analyze -> Inspect Code`, then you right-click in one of the warnings. You will see there is an option called "Disable inspection":

[image: Inspect code dialog]

Just click on it and you won't need to worry about unused declarations in your project anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know where this setting is "saved"? So it goes into the project`s settings and not all developers have to disable it themselves.

Comment: Yes. It should be located at `.idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml` inside your project directory