# Suppress values at project level in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Please check this:

```
@SuppressLint("NullSafeMutableLiveData")
@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
@Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
```

This all things I can do above functions, class and file, and base classes. But I want to do this at the project level. Like, build.gradle level so that I don't want to do it in each affecting file.

For example, I did this for RestrictedApi:

```
lint {
        abortOnError false
        disable 'RestrictedApi'
    }
```

I'm getting those suggestions, but don't know how to use it, please see image below:
[image]

Similarly, I want to set those warnings. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45759720/6819340?

Comment: Hi @Darshan Thanks for the comment. I saw the answer, but that is not an expected answer. I don't want to disable inspection. It is okay to give suggestion by Android Studio. Whichever things I want to suppress at project level, I'll do it manually.